# How to arrive at $(f'(x))^2<2f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

*Let we see a problem ahead of I asking what I want to ask.*

Define $f:\mathbb{R}\to(0,+\infty)$ differentiable satisfying $|f'(x)-f'(y)|\le|x-y|\,\, \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Prove: $(f'(x))^2<2f(x)$

I came up with a proof which is as follows:

> *In order to make the proof more rigorous, we pointed out in advance that $f'$ is (uniformly) continuous.*
>
> 1. $\,$ If $f'(x)=0$.
>   Then through $f>0$ we arrive at the conclusion.
>
> 2. $\,$ If $f'(x)>0$.$\,\,\,$ Let $x_0=x-f'(x)$.
>
> so $f(x)=\int_{x_0}^{x}f'(t)\,dt+f(x_0)>\int_{x_0}^{x}f'(t)\,dt\ge\int_{x_0}^{x}(f'(x)+t-x)\,dt=\frac{1}{2}(f'(x))^2$
>
> 3. $\,$ If $f'(x)<0$.$\,\,\,$ Let $x_0=x-f'(x)$.
>
> so $f(x)=f(x_0)-\int_{x}^{x_0}f'(t)\,dt>\int_{x}^{x_0}-f'(t)\,dt\ge\int_{x}^{x_0}(-f'(x)+x-t)\,dt=\frac{1}{2}(f'(x))^2$

Actually I got stuck on how to arrive at $(f'(x))^2<2f(x)$.

I thought $f(x)$ is influenced by $f'(t)$ where $t$ is around $x$, so I came up with the proof as mentioned above.

But at the same time I thought that for the similar questions such as $f(x)>f'(x)$ we can construct the auxiliary function $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{e^x}$.

**So what I really want to ask is how to arrive at $(f'(x))^2<2f(x)$?**

I thought this maybe relates to the solution of $(f'(x))^2=2f(x)$.

What's more, any new ideas for the above problem are welcomed. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When exploring the values between $x$ and $x-f'(x)$, it usually makes sense to parametrize that segment as $x-sf'(x)$, $s\in[0,1]$. This avoids discuss the different cases of the order between these points.

Let $L$ be the Lipschitz constant of $f'$, then we know from the fundamental theorem that
\begin{align}
|f(x+u)-f(x)-f'(x)u|&\le\int_0^1|f'(x+su)-f'(x)|\,ds\,|u|
\\
&\le \int_us\,ds\,L|u|^2
\\
&=\frac12L|u|^2
\end{align}

Resolving the absolute value to one side it follows that
$$
f(x)+f'(x)u\ge f(x+u)-\frac12L|u|^2.
$$
Now insert $u=-\frac{f'(x)}{L}$ to find
$$
2f(x)\ge 2f\left(x-\frac{f'(x)}{L}\right)+\frac{f'(x)^2}{L}
$$
To conclude now use that $f>0$.